# Creating a solid cube in helix toolkit?

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I want to create a solid cube in helix toolkit in wpf . Assume that a solid cube around a pipe and I want to intersect it so that I can see half pipe and half solid cube . Please help me .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 3):

Make a HelixViewport3d, create a MeshBuilder object, add a cube mesh to the builder (there is a ready made method for that) add pipe (cylinder) mesh to the builder, generate the mesh, add the meshgeometry object to the viewport.

Check the basic samples in the helix sources. They're  great source of info.
When I get in front of my pc I can tell you more precisely how to do it but you should be able to piece the thing together I guess.